# measure groups showing wrong result while applying filter in ssas

Tags: sql, ssas, msbi

When I try to apply filter it is not reflecting correct count.
Client Active Status    A   -- Filter

Total No. of Clients        -- Result
1033437

Row Labels  Total No. of Clients

A   1033437

C   231546

D   265387

Grand Total 1530370

but when I select any 2 from it. It shows **1530370** as result instead of showing addition of the selected status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the issue. I found that I was using calculated field.
That's the reason the values were not reflecting after applying filter.

**I removed these calculated fields which were causing the issue and created measures with the same name and expression.**
Now it is working.